# how to solve all ignoring commands while updating kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, upgrade

when i run sudo spt update...i get all ignoring commands

```
Hit:1 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                            
N: Ignoring file 'cybermax-dexter-ubuntu-sdl2-backport-jammy.list.old' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.list.old' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'brave-browser-release.list.old' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'webupd8team-ubuntu-java-jammy.list.old' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'microsoft-prod.list.old' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

can anyone help with it?

Comment: you tried this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/458598/how-do-remove-ignoring-file-in-directory-etc-apt-sources-list-d-as-it-has-an

Answer (score 2):

Rename the five files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` that generated the `N: Ignoring file ... in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension` error messages.

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo mv cybermax-dexter-ubuntu-sdl2-backport-jammy.list.old cybermax-dexter-ubuntu-sdl2-backport-jammy.list
sudo mv google-chrome.list.old google-chrome.list
sudo mv brave-browser-release.list.old brave-browser-release.list
sudo mv webupd8team-ubuntu-java-jammy.list.old webupd8team-ubuntu-java-jammy.list
sudo mv microsoft-prod.list.old microsoft-prod.list
sudo apt update
```

Alternatively if you don't need any of these software sources anymore you can delete them:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/  
sudo rm cybermax-dexter-ubuntu-sdl2-backport-jammy.list.old google-chrome.list.old brave-browser-release.list.old webupd8team-ubuntu-java-jammy.list.old microsoft-prod.list.old 
sudo apt update
```